Bootstrap dynamic tabs remaining active after switching tab, causing stacking of elements
I am creating a website similar to a text editor for my university project using Bootstrap as a framework. I have used the dynamic tabs in order to create the menus for the website. This is the code I have:


    <!--Bootstrap styling import-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Creation of the dynamic tabs-->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link px-4" id="file-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#file-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="file-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">File</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link active px-4" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home-tab-pane" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link px-4" id="edit-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#edit-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="edit-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Edit</button>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <button class="nav-link px-4" id="layout-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#layout-tab-pane" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="layout-tab-pane" aria-selected="false">Layout</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content border border-1" id="myTabContent">
        <!--Content in the file tab-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="file-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="file-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
        <!--Content in the home tab-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active d-flex justify-content-center my-2" id="home-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab" tabindex="0">
          <div class="d-flex align-items-center overflow-auto gap-1">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="boldButton" data-bs-toggle="button"><b>B</b></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="italicsButton" data-bs-toggle="button"><i>I</i></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="underlineButton" data-bs-toggle="button"><u>U</u></button>
            <select class="ms-5" name="font" id="font">
                <option value="times-new-roman">Times New Roman</option>
                <option value="helvetica">Helvetica</option>
                <option value="garamond">Garamond</option>
                <option value="calibri">Calibri</option>
                <option value="arial">Arial</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="increaseFontSize">Size△</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn me-5" id="decreaseFontSize">Size▽</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="button">Left Align</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="button">Centre Align</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="button">Right Align</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="button">Justify</button>
            <select name="spacing" id="spacing">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Line Spacing</option>
                <option value="0.5">0.5</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="1.5">1.5 (Default)</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="2.5">2.5</option>
            </select>
            <button type="button" class="btn ms-5">Bulleted List</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Numbered List</button>
          </div> 
        </div>
        <!--Content in the edit tab-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade d-flex justify-content-center my-2" id="edit-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="edit-tab" tabindex="0">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center overflow-auto gap-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn">Undo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Content in the layout tab-->
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="layout-tab-pane" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="layout-tab" tabindex="0">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="text-area d-flex justify-content-center my-5">
        <div id="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
    </div>
    <!--Bootstrap js import-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



However, when I view the webpage the tabs work fine, but switching from the home to the edit tab, the button within the edit tab stacks below within the div, as if the buttons from the home tab are still there, they are just invisible. Adding anymore buttons within a different tab (layout for example), will then stack that below the button in the edit tab. This is what it looks like:

I have tried removing my own stylesheet and JS code, changing from a list to div elements, changing them from buttons to links to the their individual div elements but nothing is working.

Correct, if you check in devtools thediv with id=' home-tab-pane'  (and other tabs) have opacity set to 0 and not display set to none. that is why the edit btn is below the home-tab-pane with opacity set to 0

It's because you added the d-flex class to your tab panes - that class applies display: flex !important;, and therefor overwrites the simple display: none; that would get applied to the panes by default via the .tab-content>.tab-pane rule. Remove that class from the panes. You have it added to the single child div container inside those panes already, so move the alignment classes, such as justify-content-center, onto the child as well.

Remove the d-flex class from the tab panes. d-flex applies the style display: flex !important, which overwrites the class display: none; that is automatically applied to the panes by through .tab-content>.tab-pane rule. You already have it added to the single child div container inside those panes anyways. Be sure to also move the justify-content onto the child as well.
